# looping a statement in ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu

In the Ubuntu terminal, how do I loop a command like

```
python myscript.py
```

so that it runs every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) rather than loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to schedule something, then you want crontab.

But if this is temporary (i.e. checking to see if a file has appeared or whatever), then here's how you could do this

`while true ; do python myscript.py ; sleep 15m; done`

This will execute forever ("while true") so you'll have to ctrl-c to cancel it when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use something like cron instead, but... if you are sure you want something to run in the same terminal-window every N minutes (or seconds, actually), you could use the 'watch' command.

```
watch -n 60 python myscripy.py
```

Answer (score 0):

using crontab you can add an entry like `*/15 * * * * python /path/to/myscript.py`